# Is SSH required to use the Zend framework skeleton in the "Getting Started" guide?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have installed the Zend framework using the application contained within my shared hosting account. The problem appears to be that the shared hosting does not allow SSH which leads me to think that I cannot setup the "skeleton" package referred to by the "getting started" guide. Is it not possible to install the "skeleton" unless I can access SSH?

I have another question. This could possibly form a solution if it is viable...

If I install this whole package as a local app using Xampp (which I am reasonably familiar with) would I be able to "simply" upload the entire project to the shared hosting server after setting up the package with composer? I am possibly using the word "simply" rather flippantly there.

I originally wanted to develop on the server itself because that is how I normally do things. I am willing to do things differently. I was thinking of maybe just doing the setup (with composer) and then immediately loading it onto the server for development though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no issues developing on your local setup, and then uploading via FTP, there's no requirement for SSH.

If you use composer on your local machine, it should take care of autoloading for you, which uses relative paths so it should work fine when uploading to your remote host.

1) Use composer to get your dependencies on your local machine.

2) Upload to remote host, making sure the document root is in the correct place to be served by the web server.
For example, when using the ZF2 Skeleton, you can place all files one level above your document root, having your 'public' folder in your document root.

All should work as expected :)

Comment: I believe that I will just go down that route then and develop on my machine (which I tend not to like doing). I am just concerned about all the routing issues that may come about afterwards once it is on the server. I think this will need to be a separate question when the time comes though.

Comment: There should be no issues with routing etc, as long as your rewrites/htaccess etc are setup correctly.

Comment: Your answer has provided me with enough information for now and I will therefore accept it. Hopefully my question was clear and useful and warrants an up-vote from someone (not that I am, in any way, making any kind of suggestion there).